# Send a value of a model from the controller and not in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently I have users who are selecting the value from a dropdownlistfor and it gets sent through the controller like so:

```
if (model.HomeEquityDetails.LumpSumLineCredit == "Lump Sum")
        {
            loanInfo.LumpSum = true;
            loanInfo.LineOfCredit = false;
        }
        else
        {
            loanInfo.LineOfCredit = true;
            loanInfo.LumpSum = false;
```

How do I go about hardcoding this so it returns LumpSumLineCredit as always "Lump Sum" so the user no longer has to pick.  I basically want

```
HomeEquityDetails.LumpSumLineCredit
```

to always equal "Lump Sum" in the controller.  Can i just send

```
loanInfo.LumpSum = true;
```

Comment: Change the getter of <strike>`LumpSum` to always return true</strike>`LumpSumLineCredit` to always return `"Lump Sum"`?

Comment: So i can basically drop the if statement and just have loanInfo.LumpSum = true; ?

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake in my comment and should have said `LumpSumLineCredit` and `"Lump Sum"`. But the idea is the same as you say, just don't do the test.

Comment: If you don't use or need the property `LumpSumLineCredit`, why do you have it?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly OT but assuming you wanted to keep the same logic above the code could be simpllified to:

```
loanInfo.LumpSum =  model.HomeEquityDetails.LumpSumLineCredit == "Lump Sum";
loanInfo.LineOfCredit = !loanInfo.LumpSum;
```

That ultimately removes the if test and simplifies the code, and if the requirement to test for "Lump Sum" was no longer there then:

```
loanInfo.LumpSum =  true;
loanInfo.LineOfCredit = !loanInfo.LumpSum;
```

It also seems like you will want to specify the loan type so having booleans is going to be a maintenance nightmare assuming you have loantypes to add. You could consider the following:

```
public enum LoanTypeEnum {
   LineOfCredit,
   LumpSum
}

public struct LoanInfoStruct {
   public LoanTypeEnum LoanType {get; set; )
}
```

which means the code would simplify to assuming loanInfo is a LoanInfoStruct:

```
loanInfo.LoanType = LoanTypeEnum.LineOfCredit;
```